# In how many universities should I apply for phd in US

Tags: phd, united-states, application, statistics

I am from India and I want to pursue a PhD in statistics in the US. In each university the application fee is at least $60 which is around 4,000 Indian rupees which is a significant amount to pay for each application. It is not possible for me to apply in 50 or 100 universities. I need some guidance that how should I select universities to apply?

Comment: Americans don't apply for 50-100 either! Did someone suggest that many, or are you just joking?

Comment: By "50 or 100" I mean I can not apply in plenty universities... I am planning to apply in 10 to 15 but  I am confused how will I  select those universities.

Comment: We can't pick them for you, either; choose programs that have faculty that you'd like to work with. Consider that you'll be living in a place for 5-6 years, so you may want to choose a place you'd actually like to be for that time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Learner 10-15 is a decent amoutn.

Comment: You need to get guidance from an experienced mentor.  Nobody should be applying to more than 10 PhD programs.  You need quality applications.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you don't apply to a lot of places, but act to distribute your applications over universities at different levels. If you are really good and have a lot to offer, then one or two in the top 10, one or two with rankings around 50 or so and some in between. Some state schools, some private.

If you make a broad search you will likely hit on something. And see the [answer for the US to this linked question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368).

Note that the university ranked, say, 50th in the US is still a marvelous place to get a degree. And, most state universities typically have a lot of openings.

Answer (score 3):

10 is a good number. The idea is to have some (~3) universities in the "50-50 chance I'll be admitted" range, some universities in the "I'll be surprised if I'm admitted but if I am admitted I'm definitely attending" range, and some "safety schools" where you expect to be admitted.

You can apply to less than 10 universities as well, if you have backup plans in case of rejection everywhere (e.g. you are happy to attend an Indian university).

Comment: For a typical student, especially one from overseas, I imagine it's quite difficult to estimate admission chances.